# Prove that formula is not tautology.

Tags: intuitionistic-logic

Show Kripke's model proving that the following formula isn't tautology in intuitionistic logic. $ \neg ( p \wedge q ) \implies (\neg p \vee \neg q) $

Please help/hint me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a simple three-nodes model with $w_0$ as vertex and $w_1$ and $w_2$ as leaves [i.e. $w_i \ge w_0, i=1,2$] where :

> no atom is forced by $w_0$

and :

> $w_1 \Vdash p \ $ , $ \ w_2 \Vdash q$

will suffice.

We have $w_0 \Vdash \lnot (p \land q)$ because for all $w_i \ge w_0 : w_i \nVdash (p \land q)$.

But $w_1 \nVdash \lnot p$ and $w_2 \nVdash \lnot q$.

Comment: ok. It was so easy to come up. I thought about it but I was convinced that we have to consider also "potential" future states/worlds- I mean: Maybe there are more states which force $p$. For example: state $w_3 \ge w_2$  and $w_3 \Vdash p$? So, can we focus on finite model and we have not to worry about possible future?