# How to prove that the following three tautologies of classical logic are disallowed in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I need to prove that the following three tautologies are disallowed in intuitionistic logic.

The tautologies are:

1-double negation $\neg \neg P\equiv P$

2-Law of excluded middle $P \vee\neg P$

3-Contraposition $(P \supset Q)\equiv (\neg Q \supset \neg P) $

can somebody explain how to do this?

Comment: Use [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Semantics_of_intuitionistic_logic) to produce suitable counter-models.

Comment: [Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999070/prove-that-formula-is-not-tautology).

Comment: See also [Kripke semantics for intuitionistic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#KriSemForIntLog).

Comment: For an answer to your questions 1 and 2, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2622484/288417).

Comment: Note that $P \supset \lnot \lnot P$ and $(P \supset Q) \supset (\lnot Q \supset \lnot P)$ are provable in intuitionistic logic. Only their converses are not provable in intuiti0nistic logic.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco if I use the Kripke model here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2622456/prove-the-undecidability-of-a-formula/2622484#2622484 and then say $0 ⊮ (A \to B) \equiv (\neg A \to \neg B)$ will my proof be correct?

Comment: @KatherinD - Good idea but it is slightly more complicated: consider the Kripke model over the domain $\{0,1\}$, as the one defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2622484/288417). You should define the binary relation $\Vdash$ from $\{0,1\}$ to the set of propositional variables $\{A,B\}$ so that, according to the definition of [intuitionistic Kripke model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Semantics_of_intuitionistic_logic) for propositional logic, $0 \not\Vdash (\lnot B \to \lnot A) \to (A \to B)$.